# Why do I get error when I use ForEach in Xcode 11 Beta 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

Error message:

> Generic parameter 'ID' could not be inferred

```
ForEach(0...self.workoutsViewModel.workoutRoutine[self.workoutIndex].routine[0].exercises.count - 1) { x in

    Text("\\(x)")

}
```

Comment: That is far too less info for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The elements in the collection you pass as the first argument of `ForEach` must conform to `Identifiable`, or you must use a different initializer to specify the `KeyPath` of the id on your elements. For example, the following code does not compile:

```
struct MyModel {
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let models: [MyModel]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(models) { model in
            Text(model.name)
        }
    }
}
```

The `models` array does not satisfy the requirements of the `ForEach` initializer, namely, its elements do not conform to `Identifiable`. I can solve this in one of two ways:

1.) Extend `MyModel` to conform to `Identifiable`:

```
extension MyModel: Identifiable {
    // assuming `name` is unique, it can be used as our identifier
    var id: String { name }
}
```

2.) Use the convenience initializer on `ForEach` that allows you to specify a `KeyPath` to your identifier:

```
var body: some View {
    ForEach(models, id: \.name) { model in
        Text(model.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @daltonclaybrook is great because it explains why you're getting that error and illustrates the correct approach of creating a custom model.  But if you're looking for a temporary, quick and dirty solution this works for me in Xcode 11.2.1 and iOS 13.2 for an array of `String`:

```
ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { string in
   ...
}
```